# Pokémon Trading cards, mix & match?

Tags: pokemon

Can Pokémon xy starter decks be mixed with booster packs from other series or other starter decks? I know you can only play 60 cards but if I buy two differnt starter decks, can I build a "unique" deck from the two, using the various types of Pokémon, energy cards, trainer cards, etc?

Comment: Are you wanting to play in tournaments or are you just playing casually with friends?

Comment: My kids are playing casually against each other, may eventually take them to tournaments at our local shops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are playing casually you can mix any cards you want to as long as you have exactly 60 cards in your deck and no more than 4 of a given card (other than basic energy).

For tournaments there are a couple different formats that determine what is legal. The primary constructed formats that are played at tournaments are Standard (formerly Modified), Expanded, and Unlimited. For any of these formats if a card is legal in the format you can use copies from previous sets. The cards that are legal in each of these formats as of [4/19/16](http://file:///C:/Users/jallen/Downloads/2017%20Play!%20Pok%C3%A9mon%20TCG%20Rules%20and%20Formats.pdf) are as follows:

### Standard

- XY—Kalos Starter Set
- XY
- XY—Flashfire
- XY—Furious Fists
- XY: Trainer Kit
- XY01 and higher
- Other sets 3 weeks after their release in the United States

### Expanded

- Black & White
- Black & White—Emerging Powers
- Black & White—Noble Victories
- Black & White—Next Destinies
- Black & White—Dark Explorers
- Black & White—Dragon Vault
- Black & White—Dragons Exalted
- Black & White—Boundaries Crossed
- Black & White—Plasma Storm
- Black & White—Plasma Freeze
- Black & White—Plasma Blast
- Black & White—Legendary Treasures
- BW: Trainer Kit
- XY—Kalos Starter Set
- XY
- XY—Flashfire
- XY—Furious Fists
- McDonald’s Collection 2011
- McDonald’s Collection 2012
- McDonald’s Collection 2014
- XY: Trainer Kit
- Black Star Promo Cards: BW01 and higher, XY01 and higher.
- Additional expansions become legal three weeks after they are released in the United States.

The card Shiftry (Next Destinies 72/99) is banned in Expanded

### Unlimited

- All cards from all expansions (including promo cards) are legal in Unlimited
- Additional expansions become legal three weeks after they are released in the United States.